# Node JS Response parsing (of S3 Select response)

Tags: node.js

I am trying to parse a response from an API which is a streamed response: but the structure looks different from any other response.
A sample can be found  in [python](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/querying-data-without-servers-or-databases-using-amazon-s3-select/).

```
 let body = []

      response.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body.push(chunk)
      })
        .on('end', function() {

          const bff = Buffer.concat(body).toString("utf-8")
          console.log( bff)

        })
```

it returns like:

```
�U
:content-typeapplication/octet-stream
                                     :event-typeRecordsJane,(949) 123-45567,Chicago,Developer
:content-typtext/xml
                    :event-typeStats<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Stats><BytesScanned>339</Byt:message-typeeventocessed>339</BytesProcessed><BytesReturned>39</BytesReturned></Stats>�h�8(�Ƅ�
                  :event-typeEndϗӒ
```

what is the correct way to parse such a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bytes parsing because it is a nested message.
The spec to parse can be found here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTSelectObjectAppendix.html